# Iterable toMap with concrete map implementation

Tags: scala

There is an `Iterable(k->v)` which I want to convert into `immutable.Map` saving the ordering of elements. The best target `Map` type is `ListMap`. Is there any way to get `ListMap` using `toMap` on `Iterable`?

Comment: The return type of [`Iterable.toMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Iterable) is `immutable.Map`. Is that ambiguous, or are you asking how to modify the library?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
scala> val iterable =  Iterable("a" -> 3,"t" -> 5,"y" -> 1, "c" -> 4)
iterable: Iterable[(String, Int)] = List((a,3), (t,5), (y,1), (c,4))

scala> import collection.immutable.ListMap
import collection.immutable.ListMap

scala> ListMap(iterable.toSeq:_*)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[String,Int] = Map(a -> 3, t -> 5, y -> 1, c -> 4)
```

**Update**
You have to extends API by implicit class/method, for example:

```
scala> object IterableToListMapObject {
     | 
     |   import collection.immutable.ListMap
     | 
     |   implicit class IterableToListMap[T, U](iterable: Iterable[(T, U)]) {
     |     def toListMap: ListMap[T, U] = {
     |       ListMap(iterable.toSeq: _*)
     |     }
     |   }
     | 
     | }
defined object IterableToListMapObject

scala> import IterableToListMapObject._
import IterableToListMapObject._

scala> val iterable = Iterable("a" -> 3,"t" -> 5)
iterable: Iterable[(String, Int)] = List((a,3), (t,5))

scala> iterable.toListMap
res0: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[String,Int] = Map(a -> 3, t -> 5)
```

Comment: @Steven Yang please check [AnyVal](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html). This case is not for it.

Comment: How is it not? This case looks exactly like the case mentioned in the docs. See: RichInt